# Tables and selecting the rRow (id) to pass to a new page (so it doesn't overwrite the variable of the row selection)

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have a table and each row is clickable to send it to a new page, (DoNav) function. What I need is for a variable to be transferred to the new page (id of that row). I was going to use a session variable.

The problem is, that the last last rows variable is transferred i.e. if I have 30 rows and I click on the first row, the id of row 30 is transferred. The variable is overwritten. Each row has a DoNav (reference to the new page).

I need the code to send a PHP variable (id) with the row that is clicked. Look at this table(snippet) example (imagine each of these rows are under headers).

```
    <td>1</td> // row 1
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php')"; <?php $_SESSION['SELECTION']=1;?>>
    <td>2</td> // row 2
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
    <tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php')"; <?php $_SESSION['SELECTION']=2;?>>
    <td>3</td> // row 3
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php')"; <?php $_SESSION['SELECTION']=3;?>>
```

Now, when I click on say, the first row `$_SESSION['SELECTION']` returns 3 (the last row). Obviously it overwrites the variable. What I need is for the row that is clicked, only that row is read and passed to the new page.

Is there a simple bit of code that can be put into the

```
    <tr
```

line that will select only that row and pass the variable and not the last variable every time?

Comment: your question it not clear....

Comment: pls see below.... all I need is the correct script/php to attach a variable to a new SESSION variable without it being overwritten @VyrenMedia

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337629/to-make-this-clearer I have added a new post to make what I need clearer @VyrenMedia

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't give each tr an id and then pass the id to your function, attaching it to the querysting?  I'm not sure what you are doing in DoNav() presently.

```
onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php',this.id);"

function DoNav(url,id){
    window.location.href = url + "?id=" + id;
}

//handle querystring in php destination page
```

Comment: This doesn't entirely clear up the problem but it does suggest the correct solution. The problem is that this `<?php $_SESSION['SELECTION']=3;?>` in the tr is telling HTML nothing, it's just setting `$_SESSION['SELECTION']`. What you need to do it set that ID in the HTML, `onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php', <?php echo $some_id; ?>);"` and use the function @Seano666 suggested.

Comment: hmmm maybe, I will try this and let you know if this worked.... I hope the url,id) works and wont overwrite...thanks @Seano666

Comment: That said, really, if each of the strings in td are to be clickable they should each have anchors

Comment: function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
  document.location.href = theUrl;
  }

Comment: @user3048806 Yeah I just noticed your html is a little weird.  Why do you not have opening and closing tags around your table data elements?<tr><td></td></tr>

Comment: Hi @popnoodles and yes they do.... the table rows highlights and is cickable.... just a problem assigning the session variable to the next page

Comment: I can see what you want, I'm talking best practices. Ideally there would be an anchor in each cell which you can make fill the td with css, which in turn makes the whole row clickable, or you can use javascript to move the click event onto the tr after the page has loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt put all the code in here but everything seems to work fine except for the SESSION variable that is overwritten before it goes to the next page. The tr is for clarity that each row is clickable and I just need the variable attached and then the user is sent to a new page.

Comment: @popnoodles well that didnt work because the row is now not clickable so I guess the syntax is wrong. I really want the variable $_SESSION['SELECTION']=1, $_SESSION['SELECTION']=2 and so on for each row. All I need is an example.... The code for the function to pass the variable to the new page, the retrieval of it on the next page. I want to use the onclick and the DoNav.

Comment: That's fine but all you're doing with `$_SESSION['SELECTION']=X` is setting the variable `$_SESSION['SELECTION']`. It doesn't do anything to the HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337629/to-make-this-clearer I have added a new post to make what I need clearer @Seano666

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable `$_SESSION['SELECTION']=X` doesn't affect the HTML. You have to output something in that URL, e.g.

```
 <tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php?id=1')">...</tr>
 <tr onclick="DoNav('http://newpage.php?id=2')">...</tr>
```

Comment: I see what you are driving at @popnoodles . the id=1 and id=2 though is not a session variable. its just a variable.... I will try to turn it into a SESSION variable and see how this goes. ummm shouldn't these variables be inside the php code? id=1 etc above wont send that (php)variable to the new page

Comment: No, setting something in PHP there will not change the HTML that's outputted unless you're using it to set a variable which you then output.

Comment: `?id=1` sends `$_GET['id']` to the page as the value 1. What are you trying to do with $_SESSION? I think you need to get to grips with HTML and then PHP. There are Learn [whatever] in 24 hours books that are very useful.

Comment: you are right... I am a php junky with javascripting thrown in.... I understand what you are all putting togehter for me.... just needed the time to do this (work gets in the way)....cheers and will report back when I have it running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337629/to-make-this-clearer I have added a new post to make what I need clearer @popnoodles

Comment: Sorry I can't offer any further help, you need to first grasp the fundamentals. Props for jumping in the deep end but trust me, learning this stuff requires a more logical approach.

Comment: you did it buddy.... I didnt realise that you that you can use $_GET to pass the URL variable to php.... saved me. I would of preferred SESSION but this can do